# Nofollow tag Jquery Add More Domains

Tags: jquery, nofollow

I saw this add nofollow tag but how do i exclude more domains. The script only allows 1 url only. Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a[href*="http://"]:not([href*="http://domain.com/"])').attr('rel', 'nofollow');
    jQuery('a[href*="https://"]:not([href*="http://domain.com/"])').attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate attribute selectors in the `:not` selector with a comma:

```
jQuery('a[href*="http://"]:not([href*="http://domain.com/"],[href*="http://example.com/"])')
    .attr({ rel: 'nofollow', target: '_blank' });
```